# Using regex for column delimited file

Tags: regex

I am wondering how I can use regex to reformat the following format.
I have a file with the following style columns:

```
AG2912  
3760        3913  
3293        3920

AG2102  
3209        0201  
3021        0383
```

but I want it in the following format:

```
AG2912  
3760        3913        3293        3920  

AG2102   
3209        0201        3021        0383
```

Also, the number of rows per column vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '/^AG/ { print } /^[0-9]/ { printf "%s\t", $0 } /^$/ { printf "\n\n" } END { printf "\n" }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
AG2912
3760        3913    3293        3920    

AG2102
3209        0201    3021        0383
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify any language, I'll just put the search and replace expressions.

Search: `\n`
Replace: `\t`

Comment: I am just using regular expression.

Comment: Regular expressions are processed by a regex engine, and this engine is inside some code or editor. That's what I mean. Anyway, the answer is valid for any PCRE-compatible regex engine.